# Which color to use if no gender is selected in my mobile app?

Tags: color

I create a name chooser mobile app. I'm going to change the app theme to blue if boy names are filtered, pink if girl names are filtered. What color to use if no gender is filtered? (boy and girl names are shown at the same time) Please help because I have no idea! :)

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: You asked an idea. You will get it: Use Rainbow gradient. I cannot  write this as an answer for well before tested reasons.

Comment: Violet or purple.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your region/country you might have different conventions or standards already being used. I would look around and follow those.

Otherwise you can default to one of the more common methods of showing multi-gender things by combining the male and female symbols like this.

[image]

I would be careful using grey because it normally suggests that an option isn't valid or currently not selected/useable.